# AES random key generation

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I see many examples where the secret key is generated this way:

```
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
generator.init(KEY_LEN);
SecretKey secretKey = generator.generateKey();
```

I'm in doubt if there's a difference (even conceptual) with the following:

```
byte[] material = new byte[KEY_LEN / Byte.SIZE];
SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(material);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(material, "AES");
```

Stated that both methods are 3 lines, is there some practical impact in preferring the first over the second?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons why you would want to use the `KeyGenerator` method, which was *designed* for the purpose:

- readability: `generateKey` tells you exactly what the algorithm is doing;
- portability: e.g. when choosing a different algorithm);
- correctness: `SecretKeySpec` may not validate the key entirely;
- security: you would leave the key material exposed in the `material` variable, which may not be cleared or even garbage collected after the key is not required anymore;
- hardware support: importing key material is often not supported for hardware devices; keys should be generated on the device itself (using a specialized `KeyFactory` implementation).

There is no reason at all to use the second method. If you want to use a very specific random number generator for generating the key then you can use [one of the specialized `init` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html#init-int-java.security.SecureRandom-) but beware that this may not be compatible with hardware devices.

Comment: Note that there is now a [`destroy` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Destroyable.html#destroy--) to destroy the key after it has been used. Don't forget to handle the exception correctly!

Comment: I think your answer is the most complete. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could look at the actual source code for `generateKey()` to see the difference but ultimately they are both going to do the same steps to generate an AES key. I would argue the latter

```
byte[] material = new byte[KEY_LEN / Byte.SIZE];
SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(material);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(material, "AES");
```

is a little more brittle for the average coder, requiring them to understand the SecureRandom class. If you eliminate the second line altogether the code runs just fine with an all zero key, an obvious vulnerability that's also easy for an attacker to check. Also, using `generateKey()` can produce a properly formatted key if the algorithm has some particular requirements. For example, the now obsolete DES and Triple DES algorithms had a weird parity bit in each byte that some DES implementations expected to see.

Comment: Exactly the same steps, at least for AES. So, it's just a question of readability. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The two code examples seem to be doing the same and as already answered usually they are.

However using security devices (e. g. [HSM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), smartcards or other crypto devices) by default they won't allow exposing the key bytes so you would  be able to generate a key from arbitritrary byte array only in very limited cases..

Comment: I don't understand what do HSM, smartcards and other *key storage* devices have to do with *random key generation*

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I just claim that in some cases you may not use the second code example (you won't be able to initialize an encryption key from byte array).

Comment: @MicheleMariotti Say that you replace the software implementation with a more secure hardware solution. In that case you want to have the key generation in the same device that performs the security operations (such as encryption). Otherwise the key may be exposed to an attacker. Most hardware devices will not even let you import key material for this reason. Using `SecureRandom` is in that case not recommended. It is even possible that software implementations protect the secret key somehow so using a `KeyFactory` is indeed recommended for this reason (and the reasons given by James).

Comment: I miss something. How do you use `KeyGenerator` on an HW device? You have to register a `Provider` that generates the key on the HW calling its own internal functions?

Comment: @gusto2 thanks, I didn't know about this possibility.